# how to create model in symfony 3?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm new in symfony. I came from codeigniter. I'm trying to study symfony but I'm confuse about using the model. Unlike codeigniter, there is a model folder added when I download it. How can add model in symfony? I try to search it to google and I found this [link](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/book/1_0/en/08-Inside-the-Model-Layer). I don't know if this is the right one.

Comment: Look into services and repositories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm only partially familiar with codeigniter. My guess is Doctrine would be similar to the model.
That link you show is a really old version, don't use it at all.

Here's the latest link to the Doctrine documentation:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html

Also, you can click on the "Documentation" link menu for other useful "latest" documentation.

Comment: I already read that doc from your link. Does that mean the entity now is the model of symfony?

Comment: Yes, actually if you search on Google for "symfony model" that's what you'll get is links to the database part of Symfony.

Comment: Oh! that's nice. I read a lot of tutorial and when the time they use CRUD, they put it in the controller. What is the best practice using symfony? When Ithe time I use CRUD, I will add it to the entity class. right?

Comment: I just did a quick search for "symfony crud" and this is the result: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_doctrine_crud.html   Make sure you do some research first before asking questions. If you think I helped, give me an upvote. Thanks!

Comment: sorry. I don't have any idea there is a kind of doc that has different way using CRUD. I will read for this. thanks